# It’s it halal to have sexual thoughts?

Tags: halal-haram, sex

Am a 15 year old GIRL and I often , in my free time imagine having sex with a someone . I never act up . And I can’t stop those thoughts it’s always in my head 24/7 and this thoughts make me feel good somehow . Is it halal to have those thoughts ? If not how do I stop them?

Comment: At your age, it is due to the hormonal changes your body is going through. Try to be among friends/siblings who are religious and can keep you busy. In your free time, keep yourself occupied with reciting the Quran or listening to it's tafsir on YouTube or other Islamic videos.

Comment: It's completely fine. It's natural to be specific, and Allah does not hold us accountable for what it natural. I'd say get married :)